# How to use content that's stored in other elements?

Tags: jbox

I am trying to create multiple jBoxes using the data-attributes and I want to feed them with content from other elements.

I assumed this wouldn't be possible (out of the box), so I used a `data-jbox-content-from` attribute which is supposed to be point to the element with the content. 
But I'm confused now: I know that I should be creating a single jBox only - but I do not see how that is doable when on the other hand I need distinct calls per element to provide the content?

And to confirm my uncertainty...the fiddle isn't working. So I hope someone will find a way to do this either my fixing bugs in my "ugly" approach (`eachi`ng over the controls) or a smarter use of JS/jBox.

```
$("[data-jbox-content-from]").each(function() {
  new jBox("Tooltip", {
    theme: "TooltipDark",
    id: "jBoxTooltip_" + $(this).attr("id"),
    getTitle: "data-jbox-title",
    content: $($(this).attr("data-jbox-content-from")),
    attach: "#" + $(this).attr("id")
  }).attach();
});
```

Complete fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mbaas/pvwo0fnL/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You approach is correct. But you need to put your code into `domready`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("[data-jbox-content-from]").each(function() {
    new jBox("Tooltip", {
      theme: "TooltipDark",
      id: "jBoxTooltip_" + $(this).attr("id"),
      getTitle: "data-jbox-title",
      content: $($(this).attr("data-jbox-content-from")),
      attach: "#" + $(this).attr("id")
    });
  });
});
```

Also notice that I removed the `.attach()` method after `new jBox`. jBox does that when it initializes.

See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/StephanWagner/kqgxcda1/1/

Comment: Aargh :( Nah, too simple! Can't be! Why did I miss that :(( THANK YOU SO MUCH! Pulled my hairs over it but did not think about dom.ready...